Enormous number of amdxx64.dll threads
I'm sure I provoke it somehow, but may be somebody knows what causes it and how to deal with it. The only practical problem I have now is that I cannot find my own threads because the number of these ones is huge: 150 or so.
They don't have any meaningful call stack, also there is no symbols at Microsoft symbol server for the dll. I guess it's video related.



I don't think there's anything (documented) you can do against these amd threads. But you can name your own threads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/tips-for-debugging-threads
